# changing a given url to return only the domain

Tags: php, parse-url

I'm getting a url from a form, this way:

```
$input_website = isset($_POST['website']) ? check_plain($_POST['website']) : 'None';
```

I need to get back a naked domain name(for some API integration), for example: *http://www.example.com* will return as *example.com*
and *www.example.com* will return *example.com* etc.

I have this code now, that returns the correct url for the first case  *http://www.example.com* but returns nothing for *www.example.com* or even *example.com*:

```
function get_domain($url)
{
    $pieces = parse_url($url);
    $domain = isset($pieces['host']) ? $pieces['host'] : '';
    if (preg_match('/(?P<domain>[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]{1,63}\.[a-z\.]{2,6})$/i', $domain, $regs)) {
        return $regs['domain'];
    }
    return false;
}
```

Can you please advice on the matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing something a bit different - checking if there is http and if not, i'm adding it using this function:

```
function addHttp($website) {
    if (!preg_match("~^(?:f|ht)tps?://~i", $url)) {
        $url = "http://" . $url;
    }
    return $website;
}
```

and only then i'm sending it to my other function that return the domain.
For sure not the best way, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

As per discussion with you:

```
$url = 'www.noamddd.com';
$arrUrl = explode("/", $url);
echo $arrUrl[0];
```

**Old Answer:**

Make a function with the following code block and get the domain names.

**Try this**

more about [`parse_url`](http://php.net/parse_url)

```
$url = 'http://google.com/dhasjkdas/sadsdds/sdda/sdads.html';
$parse = parse_url($url);
print $parse['host']; //google.com
```

Also you can do this in another way:

```
echo $domain = str_ireplace('www.', '', parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST));//google.com
```

Comment: thanks. iv'e changed the code to be tis 'code' function get_domain($url)
{
    $parse = parse_url($url);
    return $parse['host'];
}

$webSite = get_domain($input_website);
'code' but it's coming back empty again.

Comment: can you please post your `url`??

Comment: I'm receiving the url from an html form, this is a url for example that ive tried and came back empty www.noamddd.com

Comment: use the url with `http://` like `http://www.noamddd.com`. otherwise it will not a url, just a string.

Comment: As i've said on the question, the function is returning the domain name when the user is return a url with http, my problem is when the user brings the url without http

Comment: Unfortunlly, still not working. the new code you wrote brings back www.noamddd.com instead of noamddd.com, and for http://www.noamddd.com it returns http:

Answer (score 0):

If you just have the URL (and not want the current domain name like [frayne-konok](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5234224/frayne-konok) suggests) and want to extract the server name, you can use a regular expression like this:

```
$serverName = preg_replace('|.*?://(.*?)/.*|', '$1', $url);
```